# How do i convert a customized date() to a epoch timestamp?

Tags: php, date, time, unix-timestamp

```
$time = date("His");


$timestamp_version = ???;
```

So it is quite obvious what i am trying to do. How can i have the variable `$time` be converted to a **timestamp**?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `strtotime($time);`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert `His` formated time to timestamp via `strtotime()` function, because to this function `His` format is unknown.

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) to fetch number of seconds:

```php
$time = date("His");
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!His', $time);
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/81884)</kbd>

or just some basic math:

```php
$time = date("His");
list($H, $i, $s) = sscanf($time, "%2d%2d%2d");
echo $H * 3600 + $i * 60 + $s;
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/81886)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `strtotime($time);` function